# How do I get the text from sticky notes using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to pull all the text from a pdf using iTextSharp. Currently I can only get the actual text on the pages, not the text contained in user comments or "sticky notes" as Adobe calls them. Is there a way of doing this? Here's my code so far, but I just get empty strings:

```
    PdfReader pdfRead = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
    AcroFields form = pdfRead.AcroFields;            

    string txt = "";
    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfRead.NumberOfPages; ++page)
    {
           PdfDictionary pagedic = pdfRead.GetPageN(page);
           PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));

           if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
                 continue;

           foreach (PdfObject A in annotarray.ArrayList)
           {
                 PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);

                 txt += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.NOTE);
                 txt += "\n";
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.TEXT))
{
     string Title = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T).ToString();
     string Content = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about C#, but you can find the counter-part [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5882/tree/tutorial/basics/src/main/java/basics/chapter03/C0306_PageAnnotations.java) (the file used in this example was [pages.pdf](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5882/tree/tutorial/basics/src/main/resources/pages.pdf?format=raw)). The output of this example is:

```
Annotation 1
/Contents: This is a post-it annotation
/Subtype: /Text
/Rect: [36, 768, 56, 788]
/T: Example
Annotation 2
/C: [0, 0, 1]
/Border: [0, 0, 0]
/A: Dictionary
/Subtype: /Link
/Rect: [66.67, 785.52, 98, 796.62]
```

The first annotation is a *sticky notes* annotation (in the words of ISO-32000-1, a *text* annotation) and the key you're looking for isn't `PdfName.NOTE`, but `PdfName.T` for the title and `PdfName.CONTENTS` for the content.